# How many computers in my spacecraft?

Tags: science-based

How many computers are in modern spacecraft and airplanes? Is it common to have one computer that does most everything, or lots of embedded systems that have specialized tasks? I'm mulling over a story idea where a failure in the "central computer" on a spacecraft causes trouble, but I'm thinking that maybe such a single point of failure is unrealistic.

Comment: Redundant computers are the rule, but that will just make the story better; when the hardened, redundant system begins to break down, defying the precautions build into it, it will be a great vehicle for the story/crisis.

Comment: Definitely! Rising tension as the computers mysteriously break down one by one, astronauts scrambling to find the cause...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best comparison may be with ships. Modern warships have computer systems out the wazoo.

First, it is important to note that the systems on a ship do not overlap. Radar processors have no interaction with sonar processors which have no interaction with anything in the engine room. So a cascading fault across multiple systems is basically impossible.

Secondly, most critical systems are redundant. For navigation we have two military grade GPS receivers, and a Garmin to boot. There are at least two surface search radars. Engineering systems are even more redundant. For the nuclear plants on carriers, every computer related to nuclear safety is compartmentalized with a dedicated power source, and duplicated.

Your best bet would be a complete power failure. Power sources are also redundant, but unusual circumstances can cause them to fail. One example was a total loss of power my my ship off the coast of Africa. We lost 1 of 3 diesel generators just as we were starting Auxiliary propulsion units, 300 HP electric motors. The transient of power transfer off the dropped diesel combined with the starting current of the APU caused a second diesel to drop, which then killed the third. All dark.

Now, that was bad news, but not all was lost. Battery power kept navigation equipment and surface radar picture online, though radar can't transmit on battery power. The engine controlling computers have their own batteries. And the engine systems are all controlled by high pressure air. With power lost, fuel flow to the engines can be shut off by pneumatic valves, while a pneumatic pump keeps oil flowing to the engine and shaft so it didn't tear itself apart before it could be stopped.

Total power failure is always protected against by engineering, but is never more than bad luck and operator error away from happening. It happened on an aircraft carrier I was on while tied to the pier at 2 am due to operator error.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to ask this question of the Space Stack Exchange site.  That being said...

Nearly every complex system (whether an aerospace vehicle or not) uses multiple computers in various configurations.

- Multiple computers that perform the same function but are ganged
  together for redundancy and for scalability.
- Specialized computers that handle one specific task.

The Space Shuttle (designed in the 70s) used two separate [flight computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/4_Pi#AP-101) systems - the primary system used 4 mutually redundant computers, with a backup running a completely different set of software.

SpaceX uses triple-redundant systems according to some sources, but there's argument about that.

The Boeing 777 uses a [triple-triple redundant](http://www.citemaster.net/get/3c501aaa-39d5-11e4-9cb6-00163e009cc7/R8.pdf) architecture.